# Holding buttons (keyboard)

Tags: keyboard

I made a wireless keyboard, but I just need 4 button for my project: left control, left shift, F1, F2.
The problem: When I hold button - it acts like many key presses and releases, but I need, that when I press & hold button - it also acts like I press & hold it.

Could you please help me?

Here is source code:

Transfer_e5.ino:  https://www.paste.org/108039

Receiver_e5.ino:  https://www.paste.org/108040

Or 1 rar package:
https://easyupload.io/o3c5sp

Thank you

Or I can put them just here, if you wish.

Receiver:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(8,7); // (ce,cs)
RF24Network network(radio);

const uint16_t this_node = 00;
const uint16_t other_node = 03;

unsigned int laser_state=0;
const unsigned long my_interval = 500;
unsigned long last_sent;
unsigned int income=0;


void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(9,INPUT_PULLUP);

  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(90,this_node);

  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
}


void loop(void){
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  network.update();
  
  if ( network.available() ) {
    RF24NetworkHeader header;
    network.read(header,&income,sizeof(income));

    if(income==10){
      Serial.println("f1");
      Keyboard.press(KEY_F1);
      income=0;
    }

    if(income==11){
      Serial.println("f2");
      Keyboard.press(KEY_F2);
      income=0;
    }

    if(income==12){
      Serial.println("ctrl");
      Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
      income=0;
    }

    if(income==13){
      Serial.println("shift");
      Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
      income=0;
    }

    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if ( now - last_sent >= my_interval  )
  {
//    Serial.print("pin ");
//    Serial.println(digitalRead(9));
    last_sent = now;
    laser_state = digitalRead(9);

    RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
    bool ok = network.write(header,&laser_state,sizeof(laser_state));
  }
}
```

Transfer

```
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(8,7);
RF24Network network(radio);

const uint16_t this_node = 03;
const uint16_t other_node = 00;

unsigned int laser_state=0;
const unsigned long interval = 5;
unsigned long last_sent;

unsigned int b1=1;
unsigned int b2=1;
unsigned int b3=1;
unsigned int b4=1;

unsigned int d1=10;
unsigned int d2=11;
unsigned int d3=12;
unsigned int d4=13;

//TR1
int btn1 = 3;
int btn2 = 4;
int btn3 = 5;
int btn4 = 6;

void setup(void)
{
//  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(btn1,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(btn2,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(btn3,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(btn4,INPUT_PULLUP);

  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(90,this_node);
}


void loop(void){
  network.update();

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if ( now - last_sent >= interval  )
  {
    last_sent = now;

    b1 = digitalRead(btn1);
    b2 = digitalRead(btn2);
    b3 = digitalRead(btn3);
    b4 = digitalRead(btn4);

    if(b1==0){
//      Serial.println("F1");
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,&d1,sizeof(d1));
    }

    if(b2==0){
//      Serial.println("F2");
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,&d2,sizeof(d2));
    }

     if(b3==0){
//      Serial.println("Ctrl");
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,&d3,sizeof(d3));
    }

    if(b4==0){
//      Serial.println("Shift");
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,&d4,sizeof(d4));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am ***NOT*** downloading some random RAR file from some random site. Post your code here if you want any help.

Comment: your right   , lol

Comment: i add codes  to the note  , thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that you send each several ms new key event and on receiver each time you get this event, you call `Keyboard.press` and right away `Keyboard.release`. So, it behaves as several key press-releases.

At sender side you should send 2 types of events:

1. Key pressed (and which button)
2. Key released (and which button)

At receiver side you should

1. When you receive "press" event, call `Keyboard.press`, and don't call `Keyboard.release`
2. When you receive "release" event, call `Keyboard.release`

**Edit: I've made changes to your source code, please, try it**

Transfer

```
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(8,7);
RF24Network network(radio);

const uint16_t this_node = 03;
const uint16_t other_node = 00;

unsigned int laser_state=0;
const unsigned long interval = 5;
unsigned long last_sent;

unsigned int b1=1;
unsigned int b2=1;
unsigned int b3=1;
unsigned int b4=1;

unsigned int d1=10;
unsigned int d2=11;
unsigned int d3=12;
unsigned int d4=13;

//TR1
int btn1 = 3;
int btn2 = 4;
int btn3 = 5;
int btn4 = 6;

void setup(void)
{
//  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(btn1,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(btn2,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(btn3,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(btn4,INPUT_PULLUP);

  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(90,this_node);
}


void loop(void){
  network.update();

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if (now - last_sent >= interval)
  {
    last_sent = now;

    auto newB1 = digitalRead(btn1);
    auto newB2 = digitalRead(btn2);
    auto newB3 = digitalRead(btn3);
    auto newB4 = digitalRead(btn4);

    unsigned int packet[2];

    if(newB1 != b1){
//      Serial.println("F1");
      packet[0] = d1;
      packet[1] = newB1;
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,packet,sizeof(packet));
    }

    if(newB2 != b2){
//      Serial.println("F2");
      packet[0] = d2;
      packet[1] = newB2;
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,packet,sizeof(packet));
    }

     if(newB3 != b3){
//      Serial.println("Ctrl");
      packet[0] = d3;
      packet[1] = newB3;
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,packet,sizeof(packet));
    }

    if(newB4 != b4){
//      Serial.println("Shift");
      packet[0] = d4;
      packet[1] = newB4;
      RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
      bool ok = network.write(header,packet,sizeof(packet));
    }

    b1 = newB1;
    b2 = newB2;
    b3 = newB3;
    b4 = newB4;
  }
}
```

Receiver

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(8,7); // (ce,cs)
RF24Network network(radio);

const uint16_t this_node = 00;
const uint16_t other_node = 03;

unsigned int laser_state=0;
const unsigned long my_interval = 500;
unsigned long last_sent;


void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(9,INPUT_PULLUP);

  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(90,this_node);

  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
}


void loop(void){
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  network.update();

  unsigned int income[2] = {0, 0};
  
  if ( network.available() ) {
    RF24NetworkHeader header;
    network.read(header,&income,sizeof(income));

    auto keyCode = income[0];
    auto keyPress = !income[1];

    if(keyCode == 10){
      Serial.println("f1");
      
      if (keyPress) {
        Keyboard.press(KEY_F1);
      } else {
        Keyboard.release(KEY_F1);
      }
    }

    if(keyCode == 11){
      Serial.println("f2");
      
      if (keyPress) {
        Keyboard.press(KEY_F2);
      } else {
        Keyboard.release(KEY_F2);
      }
    }

    if(keyCode == 12){
      Serial.println("ctrl");

      if (keyPress) {
        Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
      } else {
        Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
      }
    }

    if(keyCode == 13){
      Serial.println("shift");

      if (keyPress) {
        Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
      } else {
        Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
      }
    }

    keyCode = 0;
  }

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if ( now - last_sent >= my_interval  )
  {
//    Serial.print("pin ");
//    Serial.println(digitalRead(9));
    last_sent = now;
    laser_state = digitalRead(9);

    RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
    bool ok = network.write(header,&laser_state,sizeof(laser_state));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question  ,  what i want from this keyboard is while i am holding 3 button together  ( left control +  left shift + F1 ) then i will push F2 button   ,,,    it should work like that   ( i know i sounds stupid   but  i need that ) ,,, i will be greatful  if you could fix the codes  and send them for me  , thanks again

Comment: @AminAbbasi done

Comment: thanks again and again  , i am in  travel and it takes 2 days ,,  i will check the codes and device  at sunday and report it to you immediately ,   thanks again  and   how can i compensate   ,,, i owe you one

Comment: @AminAbbasi glad to help you, hope it will work :) If not - write again and we will try to find out what's wrong!